# How to find local maximum and minimum of function $f_{n} = x^{n} \sin x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus

How to find local maximum and minimum of function $f_{n} = x^{n} \sin x$ at $x=0$?
Where $n≥2$.

I tried to find local Maxima or minima by finding the critical points, but I'm getting no critical points since $f'_{n}$ is $0$ at $x=0$.

Moreover, the local Maxima and local minima should also depend on nature of $n$, it it is odd or even.

What is the method to find local extrema of such functions?

Comment: Do you mean near x=0?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying, but the most basic (and typically first learned) test, namely the first derivative test, leads one to consider the intervals on which $x^{n-1}(n\sin x + x \cos x)$ is positive and the intervals on which $x^{n-1}(n\sin x + x \cos x)$ is negative.

Comment: @Peter Foreman, if it is not possible to find the nature of function at a particular point then we can find its nature in its right and left eighborhood. But I'm unable to do this.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro I'm stuck on finding such intervals.

Comment: You'll have to deal with the transcendental equation $\tan x = -\frac{x}{n}.$ You can determine the approximate location of the roots by examining where the graphs of $y = \tan x$ and $y = -\frac{x}{n}$ intersect. It's probably instructive to first consider the specific special cases $n=1,$ $n=2,$ etc. [This discussion of the roots of $\tan x = x$ may be helpful.](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/13-2052391-7014308-591164/tan(x)%20=%20x.pdf) Note the nonzero roots are transcendental (p. 12 of cited slides) and probably can't be expressed in closed form (p. 13).

Comment: To determine the sign $x^{n-1}(n \sin x + x \cos x)$ on these intervals, you'll want to keep track of where the graph of $y = \tan x$ is above the graph of $y = -\frac{x}{n}$ and where the graph of $y = \tan x$ is below the graph of $y = -\frac{x}{n},$ keeping in mind that the sign of $x^{n-1}$ is negative for $x<0$ and positive for $x>0.$ This seems like a neat problem that combines computational and conceptual issues not usually seen in standard calculus max/min problems.

Comment: I just noticed that you're ONLY asking about the situation for $x=0,$ so my comments pertain to a slightly different problem, namely identifying local extrema at other points. There's an extended version of the 2nd derivative test that works when you have the first $k$ many derivatives at a point equal to zero and the $(k+1)$'st derivative at that point nonzero, but I forgot what it's called. Anyway, that result is what you want, I think. (Moments later: [OK, here's the test I was thinking of](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Higher_derivative_test).)

Comment: I'm still confused about the actual problem as stated.  Is it: *For each $n$, find the closest local maximum and(/or?) minimum of $f_n$ to $0$*?  Or is it: *Find all $n$ such that $f_n$ has a local maximum or minimum at $0$*?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: I don't think either of the questions you gave was intended. The first paragraph seems to be asking this: *For each* $n\geq2$ *how can I determine whether, at* $x=0,$ *there is a local maximum or a local minimum or neither?* The second paragraph is more confusing. I think this is what was intended: When finding critical points (where $f'=0$ or $f'$ is undefined), the point $x=0$ shows up (as one would expect), but then when applying the 2nd derivative test at $x=0,$ we get $f''(0)=0,$ and thus no conclusion can be drawn. The 3rd paragraph sounds like a hint that was given.

Answer (score 4):

If you draw a plot of $x^2\sin x$, you will see it has no minimum or maximum at $x=0$. Neither $x^{2n} \sin x$. However, $x^{2n+1} \sin x$ reaches minimum at $x=0$

Calculate $f''$ and use property that $f''(x)$ is negative at $x=x_0$ if it's maximum at $x_0$, positive in case of minimum and equals zero in case of inflection point. Note: this is not always true, but in your case it's ok*. (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point )

UPD: *in this case it is not. As Silent pointed, $f''(0)=0$, so other methods should be used (e.g. proving that $f_n(x_1)>f_n(x_0)<f_n(x_2), x_1<x_0<x_2)$) - see answer below.

Comment: Calculating second derivative does not help here!!

Answer (score 1):

You should check if $f_n$ is odd or even function. As it turns out, $f_n$ even for $n$ odd and vice versa. Also, note that for $0<x<\pi$, $f_n(x)>0$ for any $n$. And $f_n(0)=0$. Combining this with continuity of $f$, we see that $f_n$ has local min at 0 for $n$ odd, and saddle point at zero for $n$ even.

Calculating second derivative will be fatal, since in any case it is zero at point $0$.